# Why does converting a string to a number in VBA result in an incorrect value when using Match function?

Tags: excel, vba

Description: I'm attempting to use the Match function in VBA to find a value in range "U1:U5000" based on the user input from a TextBox. However, when trying to convert the TextBox value, which is a string, to a number using the Val, CDbl, or CDec functions, the resulting value is incorrect. For example, the string "80" is converted to the number 8 instead of 80.

Here's an example of the code:

```
DIDa = TextBox1.Value
MAGa = Application.Match(CDbl(DIDa), ActiveSheet.Range("U1:U5000"), 0)
If IsError(MAGa) Then
    GoTo NXT
End If
```

In the above example, DIDa has the value "80", but when I try to use Match to find the value in range "U1:U5000", I get an error while the value 80 is present in that range.

How can I convert the TextBox value to a number correctly so that I can use it in the Match function and find the correct value in the range?

Comment: I believe the `Value` property of the TextBox is a Variant, not a string. Have you tried without converting it?

Comment: _I get an error_ What exactly is the error ?

Comment: Without conversion DIDa shows correctly "80" but MAGa now is `ERROR 2042` although "80" exists in Range("U1:U5000")

Comment: Trying to do an exact match on s double is a recipe for trouble due to the inexact nature of doubles.  If the range U1:U5000 are double values I'd be using a helper column where the values in column U are converted to fixed format strings and then doing the match on the column with the fixed format strings.

Comment: What is the result of 'debug.print Typename(Textbox1.value)'.

Comment: @freeflow, it is `String`

Comment: I'd say that either the 80 in the match range is actually stored as text (in which case don't use CDbl at all) or it's not really 80 but displays that way.

Comment: I also tried `Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "@"` but that did not help

Comment: did you try Val(Dida)?

Comment: @Red Hare, I did, but same result

Comment: What happens, if you test it directly - what is the result?
MAGa = Application.Match(80, ActiveSheet.Range("U1:U5000"), 0)´
And what happens if you use the 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match

Comment: `MAGa = Application.Match(80, ActiveSheet.Range("U1:U5000"), 0` = `ERROR 2042` `MAGa = Application.Match("80", ActiveSheet.Range("U1:U5000"), 0` = "8"

Comment: So in U8 there is a Value "80" and not 80 and it should return 8 and not "8" 
Either the cell is formatted as text or it is recognized as  text. Enter the cell and press enter to see if it changes. And check if it is formatted as normal. And I recommend still do use Application.Worksheetfunction.Match and not Application.Match